# What is the best practice for designing android UI?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I am developing an enterprise application in android which has more than 50 screens, so i must look deep into memory management. I am confused about designing it's user iterface in xml or by code. What is the best practice here to have better memory management?

Comment: Why do you expect that memory management will be a problem? Have you built a prototype? Have you measured the memory consumption?

Comment: Have a look at http://mobworld.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/memory-management-in-android/

Comment: @Greg: I'm building a prototype, it may consume lot of memory as there are more number of screens. my question is that, is it possible to do better memory management designing it by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Application which has more than 50 screens.

if you have 50 screens then I suggest to use [Reuse UI Components In android.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).

But

> I am confused about designing it's user iterface in xml or by code

you can do it both way But when need same view more than one time then add view using programmatically.or sometimes you need add view dynamically then use programmatically.You can use xml layout and programmatically in one application.

> What is the best practice here to have better memory management?

both are best practice related to memory management and no one take more memory if you do interface using xml or code.

Answer (score 1):

@raneez,,,,app designing does not depend on the no of screens,it depends on type of layouts you use.Preferred layout is linear.Also images should be properly placed in the drawable folder..For memorty management you have to debug your app.and check if dere is any exception coming or not....Plz let me know if you are facing any issues still.,...Also can u provide some of the screenshots..of the app that you are going to make,.,,,,,